# puppet class syntax clarification

Tags: puppet

Currently trying to understand the puppet manifests written by another person and met the following construction in the class:

```
postgres_helper::tablespace_grant { $tablespace_grants:
    privilege => 'all',
    require => [Postgresql::Server::Role[$rolename]]
  }
```

what does **$tablespace_grants:** means in this case? First i suggested that is some kind of a title, however when i used notice to receive the value of it, it is hash:

> Tablespace_grants value is [{name => TS_INDEX_01, role => developer},
>   {name => TS_DATA01_01, role => developer}]

Comment: Actually, it is an array, which is allowed for resource titles and Puppet will iterate over it: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.9/lang_resources_advanced.html#arrays-of-titles. Try doing a `notify` instead of a `notice` so you know what the value is on the agent and not on the master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what does $tablespace_grants: means in this case? First i suggested
>   that is some kind of a title,

It is a variable reference, used, yes, as the title of a `postgres_helper::tablespace_grant` resource declaration.

> however when i used notice to receive
>   the value of it, it is hash:
>
> > Tablespace_grants value is [{name => TS_INDEX_01, role => developer},
> >     {name => TS_DATA01_01, role => developer}]

Actually, it appears to be an *array* of hashes.  An array may be used as the title of a resource declaration to compactly declare multiple resources, one for each array element.  In Puppet 4, however, [the elements are required to be strings](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/lang_resources_advanced.html#full-syntax).  Earlier versions of Puppet would stringify hashes presented as resource titles; I am uncertain offhand whether Puppet 4 still falls back on this.

In any case, it is unlikely that the overall declaration means what its original author intended, in any version of Puppet.  It looks like the intent is to declare multiple resources, each with properties specified by one of the hashes, but the given code doesn't accomplish that, and it's unclear exactly what the wanted code would be.

Comment: Maybe `create_resources` with a couple default attributes would represent the original intent?

Comment: @MattSchuchard, yes, `create_resources()` might ultimately solve the problem, but the data are not presently in a form that `create_resources()` can consume.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, if the OP is using Puppet 4, or Puppet 3 with the future parser, then an `each` construct might do the job with the data as presently arranged.

Comment: Yeah I completely agree (both comments); I was just speculating and trying to make an educated guess without being able to read his/her mind.